# Ionic 4 and ag-grid

Tags: ionic4, ag-grid

I cant see the same view of ag grids in mobile view. This is supposed to be a hybrid app. what should I do to make it look same in mobile as well?

I have tried using the percentage scale of height and widths but still cant resolve the issue.

```html
<ion-content>
    <div style="height:500px"> 
       <ag-grid-angular 
            style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" 
            class="ag-theme-balham"
            [rowData]="rowData" 
            [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
        >
        </ag-grid-angular>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

I want the mobile view and desktop view to have the complete grid.

Comment: What do you mean by this..? How big should the grid be on mobile?

Comment: if I have say four columns on desktop, it should show all the four columns on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with container `div` of your ag-grid is that you are setting an absolute value of 500px, which is why your ag-grid will only occupy 500px in height, regardless of the device size.

If your intention is to fill up the entire viewport, I would recommend you to use viewport height instead. The CSS property for that is `vh`.

```
<div style="height:100vh">
  <ag-grid-angular 
    style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" 
    class="ag-theme-balham"
    [rowData]="rowData" 
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
    >
  </ag-grid-angular>
</div>
```

I have made a demo over [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/aggrid-demo-wye8ed?file=src/app/app.component.html). You may open use the 'open in new window' tab on stackblitz to view them on different viewport sizes.

Comment: @Siku my example is for height. I wasn't aware that you are referring to cell width before I posted this..